# Brilho do ie7 x Chrome

Tags: css

Estou caminhando em um projeto responsivo para portfólio, e estou configurando o ie7 com pedaços de css próprio, já estou usando o modernizer.

Eu uso o ubuntu 13.10 e para rodar o IE7 uso o wine com playonlinux, e me parece que o site que estou construindo tem menos brilho que o Google Chrome que roda direto no ubuntu, isso é normal?

Lembrando que para desenvolvimento eu uso o firefox por causa do firebug, que ajuda muito.

Comment: Sinta-se a vontade de perguntar no SOPT, estamos aqui para ajudar e para sermos ajudados quando enfrentamos um problema que não conseguimos resolver.

Comment: O que exatamente é "brilho"? Está falando de `filter: brightness(2.0);`? Pode mostrar uma imagem? Coloque o código relevante. Faça um fiddle reproduzindo. Ajude-nos a te ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é normal, uma vez que cada navegador possui uma maneira própria de renderizar a página.

Existe navegadores que tem praticamente a mesma base de renderização, como é o caso do chrome e o firefox, mas o IE (internet Explorer) eu considero um navegador fora de qualquer padrão.

olha essa imagem de comparação.

[image: Comparação entre o Google Chrome e o Internet Explorer]

A própria home page do Google fica diferente nos dois navegadores, o brilho, a fonte e olha que no Google os caras são profissionais e não conseguem deixar ele o site exatamente igual no IE e no Chrome.

Comment: Não vejo diferença de brilho na imagem. O que é "brilho"?